# change span only when SQL server table changed - ajax asp.net 3.5 jQuery SQL server

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have asp.net label called **NumberLabel**.  It is changed from code-behind (asp.net/c#) by calculating the number of rows in an SQL server table called "**MyTable**".

Every time a user open this page, the same code/stored procedure is executed to bring the number.

Is there a way to to bring the same number for all users and change it only when there is an update in "**MyTable**"?  This will optimize a lot time, executions, (SQL server side and webserver side).  Does asynchronous C# exist?  Or doing that by ajax?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use application-level asp.net caching. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx